# What is the meaning of UINavigation's setHidesBackButton?

Tags: iphone

```
- (void)setHidesBackButton:(BOOL)hidesBackButton animated:(BOOL)animated
```

can anyone tell me the meaning of above statement with an example?

Answer (score 1):

it hides the back button in the left side of your navigation bar. but it does not prevent you from going back

please see

[sethidesbackbuttonyes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232557/uinavigationitem-sethidesbackbuttonyes-wont-prevent-from-going-back)

Answer (score 0):

Description in documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationItem/setHidesBackButton:animated:

Example, which hides the back button but does not animate:

```
[item setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
```