# iOS how to remove back button?

Tags: ios, navigationcontroller

I have an application with a navigation bar that pushes to a login screen view controller and then pushes to a main menu. Is there any way I can remove the back button off the main menu, so the user is unable to go back to the login screen?

Thanks!

EDIT: Using Xcode 4.3 and doing all the leg work programmatically.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can do:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

In your second view controller (the one you want to hide the button in).

Comment: Might want to re-think using the navigation stack and instead present a modal VC - see below.

Comment: For future reference, if it isn't working for you just put that code in viewDidAppear: and it will start working.

Comment: self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true for Swift 4+

Answer (score 9):

Peters answer is correct, although I think the better question is why?  In a schema like yours where you are wanting to login a user, instead of using a Pushed VC, present a Modal VC and use a delegate method to get back the userinfo that was obtained in the Login process.  I can post a complete code example if you need it, but it sounds like you have the details worked out with your login process.  Just use:

```
presentModalViewController
```

instead of:

```
pushViewController
```

That way, you don't have to worry about the navigation stack and doing something that isn't really in-line with the user interface guidelines.

Answer (score 8):

In swift

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Comment: It works, but the swipe back gesture gonna be lost!

Answer (score 6):

The above code did not work for me. As suggested in [UINavigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES won't prevent from going back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232557/uinavigationitem-sethidesbackbuttonyes-wont-prevent-from-going-back),
I had to use:

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIView alloc] init]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Or

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried in Xcode7.3.1, swift

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

It only hide the back arrow and disabled the back action, but I can still see the name of the previous view controller.

For those who want to also hide the name of the previous view controller, try [Yoga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499423/ios-how-to-remove-back-button#14675057) works for me. In swift

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIView())
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case you need to toggle show/hide the back button:

```swift
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true/false
```

And keep the swipe back gesture:

```swift
extension YourViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {}
```

And

```swift
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```